# Refinery CMS with existing RoR application "undefined local variable or method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm very new to RoR and Refinery. I have an existing rails app for rails 4.1.5 and I'm trying to integrate Refinery CMS. The app is very simple, mostly static pages without any user accounts or sessions. I installed refinery following this guide:

http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app

I mounted refinery in '/subfolder'. When I log into the refinery CMS page, it has only the initial default pages (home and about), with place-holders. When I try to switch to my website or add one of my pages, it gives me this error:

```
NameError in Refinery::Pages#home

Showing /home/rails_projects/application/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #28 raised:

undefined local variable or method `team_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004e8bc60>:0x00000006be3768>
```

The application still works fine, but I cannot get it to work with the CMS. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer to this question (thanks to parndt in the refinery cms google group):

"Make sure that you prefix any existing routes in your application with `main_app` e.g. `main_app.team_path` as adding an engine causes Rails to behave like this."